# Comparing two list in C# using Linq and returning the duplicate numbers using user input from a numeric up and down box

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to compare the two randomly generated lists, they need to compare the totals of the dice within the code and return the amount of duplicates of the number selected by the user. The user has a numeric up and down box to select the number between 1-12 and the program will return how many of the specified number is list between the two lists.

```
       int die1, die2;
        int[] roll1 = new int[101];
        int[] roll2 = new int[101];

        //set Array
        Random dice = new Random();

    private void DiceButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {




        //sets value to the variables and for loop to generate 100 rolls
        for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
        {
            die1 = dice.Next(1, 7);
            die2 = dice.Next(1, 7);

            //displays picture of dice
            LblDie1.ImageIndex = die1;
            LblDie2.ImageIndex = die2;

            //displays roll in listbox
            roll1.SetValue(die1 + die2, i);
            listBox1.Items.Add(die1.ToString() + " + " + die2.ToString() + " = " + (die1 + die2).ToString() + "  Roll: " + i.ToString());
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
        {
            die1 = dice.Next(1, 7);
            die2 = dice.Next(1, 7);

            //displays picture of dice
            LblDie1.ImageIndex = die1;
            LblDie2.ImageIndex = die2;

            //displays roll in listbox
            roll2.SetValue(die1 + die2, i);
            listBox2.Items.Add(die1.ToString() + " + " + die2.ToString() + " = " + (die1 + die2).ToString() + "  Roll: " + i.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var count = roll1.Intersect(roll2);

        foreach(var number in count)

            listBox4.Items.Add(count.ToString()); 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why not use `List1.Intersect(List2)`?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I am using the intersect method, but I need to have the program respond to a user selecting the value of 1-12 on a numerical up and down box. I cannot figure out how to write the code for that.

Comment: By the way, why are you not starting your indices at 0? Looking at your code I don't see any obvious reason for going from 1 to 101 instead of 0 to 100?

Comment: Well, you need to have a ListBox with values 1-12. When the user changes his selection, you get the value, say `UserSelectedValue` using the SelectedIndexChanged method and then do something like `Results.Contains(UserSelectedValue)`. Is that what you're looking for?
But then, what you should do is keep a list of the sum of each roll, so you can compare the selection to each roll.

Comment: Oh yeah good point, that is something I will update in my code thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the elements of both list boxes, so you get two lists, say `List1` and `List2`, then you do `List1.Intersect(list2)` and the result is a third list containing all common elements to both `List1` and `List2`.

What you then do with the third list is up to you, but as I understand your question, this seems to be what you are looking for.

Have a look here for more information https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb910215(v=vs.90).aspx

UPDATE

I see what you are trying to do now.

`NumericUpDown` has got a `ValueChanged` event. Use that to get the current value selected by the user, `UserSelectedValue`. 
If you want to know how many times the selected value occurs in both lists simultaneously, you can do something like `List1.Count(UserSelectedValue) + List2.Count(UserSelectedValue)`, which should return how many times the value selected by the user has popped up in both lists

Comment: Thank you very much for your input on the question. How would I go about linking a numeric up and down box to have the user select the value to be compared within the lists?

Comment: Updated my answer, but still not sure if I fully understand what result you are trying to get...

Comment: OK I'm unsure of how I implement what you are saying into my code now. I understand what you are saying with the NumericUpDown and having a ValueChanged event but I need to figure out how to link it with the search button event and return the total of the selected value in the NumericUpDown to the list box.

Comment: The first part is not very hard, you forget about the `ValueChanged` event and instead just get the currently selected value when the search button is clicked (using the `.Value` property). Then you carry out the calculation of the total on your lists and load that into the `ListBox`.

Comment: OK I've figured it out I needed to add like you said the var count1 = list1.Count(x => x.ToString == numericUpDown.Value.ToString);

Comment: Yes, or you could do the opposite, like `var count1 = list1.Count(x => (int)x == numericUpDown.Value);`, it's ever so slightly shorter. Glad you got it sorted in any case! :)